# Cannot invoke 'validate' with an argument list of type '(delegate:viewController)'

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to use a pod called SwiftValidator.

I've tried to follow the instructions from the GitHub page but I don't know how to fix the following error:

> Cannot invoke 'validate' with an argument list of type '(delegate:viewController)'

Here you can find the framework: 
https://github.com/jpotts18/SwiftValidator

**EDIT:**

Here is my Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Validation
    validator.registerField(tfName, rules: [RequiredRule(), FullNameRule()])
}

@IBAction func btnValidatePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        validator.validate(delegate:self) //Error Line
    }

//MARK: - Validation

func validationSuccessful() {

}

func validationFailed(errors:[UITextField:ValidationError]) {
    // turn the fields to red
    for (field, error) in validator.errors {
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        error.errorLabel?.text = error.errorMessage // works if you added labels
        error.errorLabel?.hidden = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is a bit vague... you should provide the code that is generating the error.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your error is that you are not implementing the necessary Delegate. The view controller where you are trying to make the validation should look like this:

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController, ValidationDelegate {
   (..)
}
```